# First adventure for a beginner

Tags: hearthstone

At the moment in Hearthstone I feel a bit weak. I have been doing pretty well for a newbie with the Mage to the point I start seeing some pretty insane cards, like Death Wing and Aviana.

Meanwhile, I am still using a few basic Murlocs, some basic 2/3 cards and nothing special at all.

I have read that the 3 adventures you can play give some pretty good cards and I am not a big fan of opening a pack with some random cards in it. So from those three adventures, which one would be the best to complete as a beginner that is looking for some new cards that work for multiple classes?

The adventures I am talking about are the Curse of Naxxramas, League of Explorers and Blackrock Mountain.

Comment: Are you playing ranked or unranked? I believe unranked matches are random rather than by experience.

Comment: As far as I have found out unranked matches do have some kind of hidden MMR. From my first 20 or so unranked games managed to win almost all of them which seems to put me against veterans now. I also hate the fact that every class shares the MMR, making it very hard to play other classes.

Comment: It is quite broad, of course, if you want to know this for all classes + type of decks. It is also quite opinion based, it depends heavily on what kind of decks you want to play. Of course you can view the cards you'll earn and decided on that what adventure you'll persue. I did Naxx untill I got the SLudge Belcher, then Blackrock untill Flamewaker (I also only play mage).

Comment: There is also an amazing possibility in Elise Starseeker from the league of adventurers. It may only be pulled off well now and then, but finding the map and then the golden monkey will convert your remaining deck into legendaries. She can hold her own too at 3/5 for 4 mana.

Comment: I don't mind information about different kind of decks, but I doubt I will be able to create one anytime soon. For now I prefer cards that are generally just usefull/good.

Comment: Actually i thoroughly recommend league of adventurers if you have nothing in mind already. The discover mechanic may work very well for you, giving you access to cards you havent unlocked yet. And the legendaries each allow an interesting, different tactic i.e. Reno Jackson heals you to 30 if you have no duplicate cards left in your deck

Comment: to be honest just keep getting gvg packs till you get dr. boom. I have him along with archmage antonidas and nexus champion sarrad ind in my mech mage they save you so many times

Comment: This question may need to be updated in response to [the announcement of the Standard format](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Standard game mode

The adventures available for Standard are those released in the last two years.

**Blackrock Mountain** is the second adventure ever released in Hearthstone, with the first being Naxxramas (see below, in the "Wild game mode" section). The dragons you can get from this adventure are heavily featured in Dragon-themed decks (usually for Priests and Warriors). There are anyway some non-dragon cards that should be highlighted:

- [Emperor Thaurissan](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Emperor_Thaurissan) a.k.a. Tarzan, a.k.a. "I won't survive more than a turn on the field" is considered by some the most broken card in the game, allowing insanely good combos to become reality. Lowering the cards cost is good, lowering it permanently is very good, doing it every turn while he's on the field is *insanely* good. Being the reward for the first wing of the adventure means also that he's very easy to get.
- [Imp Gang Boss](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Imp_Gang_Boss), while being a class card (Warlock), is probably one of the best cards of the expansion. Nice body, token generation, good interaction with the Warlock tools, it fits in many archetypes for the class.
- [Flamewaker](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Flamewaker) is the core of Mage's Tempo Decks and finds some use also in spell-heavy decks.

Most of the other cards in this expansion are situational and/or used only in very specific deck archetypes.

**League of Explorers** offers the highest "card density" of any other adventure (45 cards for 4 wings vs 30-31 cards for 5 wings), giving you the best price/card ratio. This expansion singlehandedly created new deck archetypes and revitalized half-dead classes.

- [Reno Jackson](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Reno_Jackson) has been one of the biggest surprises of this expansion. Considered by many a gimmicky card before release, has proved its worth many times after getting in the hands of the players. Many classes have now a Reno-themed deck, with Warlock being probably the one that puts it to its best use.
- [Entomb](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Entomb) confirms once more the Priest as the most annoying class to play against. An unconditional removal that avoids deathrattles and gives its target to you is the source of a lot of frustration for anyone that faces a Priest.
- [Sir Finley Mrrgglton](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sir_Finley_Mrrgglton) and [Tunnel Trogg](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tunnel_Trogg) have rescued Shamans from the dark pit they had fallen in, letting Shaman decks (or at least one of them, Aggro Shaman) to be once again competitive on the ladder.

**One Night in Karazhan**, released in August 2016, is the latest expansion at the moment of this edit. It offers the same card/wing ratio of LoE. Even if not impactful as the previous adventure, it still features many good cards.

- [Barnes](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Barnes) is probably the most powerful card of the adventure. Adding to the already decent body the possibility to get a mini-Sylvanas or mini-Ragnaros so early can be match-defining.
- [Spirit Claws](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Spirit_Claws) and [Maelstrom Portal](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Maelstrom_Portal) cemented the already powerful position of Shamans in the game, making Midrange Shaman the new king of the meta.

## Wild game mode

At the moment of this writing the adventures not included in the Standard rotation (so only Naxxramas currently), cannot be bought in any way. Their reward cards anyway can still be crafted with the Arcane Dust.

**Naxxramas** was probably the best adventure to get as a beginner, since it gave you a lot of powerful tools for many classes. Unfortunately, with the arrival of the Standard format, its cards have been rotated out and are only available in Wild games. It still features some pretty great cards:

- [Mad scientist](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mad_Scientist) is a staple in many Hunter and Mage decks. For these classes it's a must-have.
- [Haunted Creeper](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Haunted_Creeper) is played in many zoo/face/token decks (Druid, Warlock, Hunter). For the Hunter it has double value since it's also a Beast, enabling many deck synergies.
- [Nerubian Egg](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerubian_Egg) is also widely used for its stickyness. Warlocks especially love this card.
- [Sludge Belcher](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sludge_Belcher) is one of the best Taunt cards in the game. One of the few cards in the game that I've seen being used by every class.
- [Zombie Chow](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Zombie_Chow) is very useful in control decks to stop early turns' aggro and has also some use in midrange.
- [Loatheb](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Loatheb) adds to a big body the ability to disrupt your opponent's next turn

These are just a few examples, this adventure is filled with good cards. Almost every high-ranking deck on the ladder before the Standard update had at least a card from this expansion, and most of them are still played in Wild these days.

## So, for the actual answer:

Get the **League of Explorers**. There are many good cards for almost every class, some of which are very powerful and/or class defining (like Reno or Tunnel Trogg). While it's close to being rotated out of Standard, there are still some months before that happens.

If you're planning to play in Wild anyway and have some spare Dust, keep in mind that the Naxxramas cards are still craftable and among them are some of the most powerful cards in the whole game.

Comment: This is a great answer, however is Brann Bronzebeard not worth a mention simply for his low cost for high reward in the form of double battlecries?

Comment: @nickson104 I initially put Brann in my answer, but then, after thinking about it a little, I've realized that, while being powerful, he has a narrower scope when compared to the other cards I've mentioned. I've been hesitant about Reno too, but he's been such a game-changer that I thought he was worth mentioning instead.

Comment: Well reasoned. You are correct, Brann would require a number of battlecry minions in the deck to be effective whereas the others can have great effect regardless. And yes, Reno can be crazy good

Comment: I definitly know about Reno. Somebody played him against me as I was about to win. I took him out and the other player had that secret that returns 2 copies of a killed minion to his hand. I do not like Reno....

Comment: @Bl00dylicious that's the worst part of Reno decks, if you're not aware you're playing against one it seems you're winning by a landslide, only to have your dreams crushed when you're almost celebrating your victory.

Comment: @Bl00dylicious I've updated my answer, since two days ago Blizzard has made an announcement: they're going to introduce formats in Hearthstone. I suggest you to read the whole announcement here: http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505

Comment: All Naxxramas cards will not be allowed in the new Standard mode, which was just recently announced by Blizzard ( http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016 ). So this is not recommendable any more.

Comment: @Rob I already edited the answer previously to explain the introduction of the formats in Hearthstone, but I've tried to make it clearer now editing it further.

Comment: @Kappei Brann works well with a C'Thun deck due to the high number of battlecry minions with effects that can actually be doubled.

Answer (score 10):

**Curse of Naxrammas**
Many mage decks seen in ladder (e.g. freeze mage) feature and can rely heavily on Mad Scientist, to allow for early board presence. It also enables you to play secrets without losing tempo. Some variations of freeze mage also make use of Sludge Belcher and Duplicate. If you are leaning more towards the style of play that freeze mage offers, Curse of Naxxramas is probably the way to go.

**Blackrock Mountain**
Blackrock mountain upgrades the mages toolkit with Flamewaker. Flamewaker is seen a lot in spell heavy mage decks and tempo decks. Emperor Thaurissan is another noteworthy card, as it is featured in freeze mage type decks also.

**League of Explorers**
For mage, League of Explorers offers less than the previous two adventures. However, cards like summoning stone and flaming torch have seen some play in ladder, though not in decks that are as viable as those such as Freeze and Flamewaker mage.

Overall it comes down to your playstyle, both Curse of Naxxramas and Blackrock Mountain have cards that feature in most viable mage decks, so either is a solid choice.

Comment: A good answer, however this covers ONLY mage decks, the OP asked for cards for multiple classes. The answer still stands however

Comment: @nickson104 sorry I had misunderstood question and though op was asking about Mage specifically. Will update with references to all classes

Comment: I'd love to see other classes as well. Although I have been most succesfull with Mage I like trying other Classes as well.

Comment: All Naxxramas cards will not be allowed in the new Standard mode, which was just recently announced by Blizzard ( http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016 ). So this is not recommendable any more.

Answer (score 4):

As a new player to Hearthstone, the two goals you should have are to open **Naxxramas** and buy exclusively **Goblins vs. Gnomes** packs with your gold.

Naxxramas has the most defining and useful cards across multiple classes including **Haunted Creeper**, **Zombie Chow**, **Loatheb**, **Sludge Belcher**, **Mad Scientist** and a few of the class cards are staples in many decks such as **Death's Bite** for Warrior, **Duplicate** for Mage, and **Dark Cultist** for Priest.

Goblins vs. Gnomes features the most broken cards in the game arguably and is the reason that The Grand Tournament cards feel so underwhelming.  These cards include **Piloted Shredder** (most used Neutral card in the game), **Dr. Boom** (most used Legendary in the game), along with the most dominant tribe **Mech** being a majority of the cards.  Because you mention playing Mage, Tempo Mage gets a good portion of it's cards from this expansion in the form of **Flame Cannon**, **Clockwork Gnome**, **Unstable Portal**.

Following this pattern of buying cards, you should have good approximations of top tier decks faster than any other card buying strategy.

- Most-used statistics taken from personal scraping of Hearthpwn.com

Comment: All Naxxramas cards will not be allowed in the new Standard mode, which was just recently announced by Blizzard ( http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016 ). So this is not recommendable any more.

Answer (score 4):

Now, after the [recent announcement from Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/19995505/a-new-way-to-play-2-2-2016), I would say beginners should avoid Naxxramas, since the cards will not be allowed in Standard mode. Also buying packs from Goblin vs. Gnomes is not recommended any more, because they will not be allowed, either. Everything else from the other answers is still true.